Ubuntu 22.04 USB tethering fails after kernel upgrade
After upgrading Ubuntu 22.04.4 from kernel 5.15.0-116 to 6.5.0-44 the USB tethering no longer works.
If I reboot (Grub Advance) into kernel 5.15 then it works again!
After booting into 6.5 only MTP file transfer works.
I am using the same Android phone for all instances.

Did you upgrade to 6.5 kernel or did a regular system upgrade do this?

If the GA kernel stack works (ie. 5.15), why not just use it? (instead of switching to HWE which is currently 6.5, but will soon swap to 6.8 which is currently in -proposed)

I need 6.2 or later to add support for the RTL8812B usb wifi driver.  Which is the end goal so I don't need to tether by the phone at all.

After adding the linux-modules-extra package both the RTL88X2 device and the mobile tether began working.
I compared the packages between the 5.15 and 6.5 and the modules-extra was a difference.
